# Where is the last piece of evidence?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I talked to the Cheshire Cat, and he mentioned that there are 4 pieces of evidence I can have to prove Alice is innocent.

I have the Footprints, the Stench, and the Antenna, but for the life of me, I cannot find a fourth thing. Was the Cheshire Cat lying to me? Is there a fourth piece of evidence?

If there is, how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hard to explain. You have to get on top of the faucet in the main room and jump across to get it. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSHsYEVuho4#t=1m37s) will show you better than I can explain.

Basically:

- Go the the lotus forest
- Take the first area on the right, where you can jump up the the lily-pad type things
- Go "backwards" towards where you came in from the throne room at, and in the corner there is a door back into the main room
- You'll fall onto a faucet, and it is to Sora's right if you are facing into the room, on a ledge.